# How to pass environment variable from squishGUI python to C++ Visual Studio project

Tags: python, c++, variables, environment

I have a GUI application in C++ Visual Studio and a project in squishGUI using python language. 
The squishGUI project is to do automation test for C++ application.

I want to have a variable in squishGUI and pass it to C++ VS project as environment variable (or as anything else that can fix my below purpose...).
My purpose is that, in C++ source code, I can use that environment variable for other processes (e.g. flow control, branch condition, etc...)

In other words, is it possible to have a communication (e.g. variable sharing, data transfer...) between squishGUI python and C++ VS project?

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated and thanked :)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to use your environment variable?

Comment: Environment variables can be passed from a parent process to a child.  If you indulge in DLL inoculation then it can be done between unrelated processes, but that's probably not a world you want to enter.  Is it Visual Studio you want to communicate with, or your app?  Named pipes are a good IPC mechanism on Windows.

Comment: I think I can use a shared file between 2 application instead of env variable or named pipes